# Can I create a Handle without a file?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to create a dump in windows with the function `MiniDumpWriteDump`. The problem is that that function takes a Handle to a file to write the result to. I want the data in memory so that I can send it over the internet. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to create a handle without a file backing it and I can just get a pointer to the data?

Comment: Can you comment about the question instead of voting to close or downvote?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What's wrong with saving the dump to a temporary file, then sending the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use memory mapped files. See here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You need to pass hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and specify maximal size of file. Please, check msdn for the details.

Comment: That seems very unlikely to work, and certainly isn't supported.  A file mapping handle is meant to be passed to functions such as `MapViewOfFile`, it is not a replacement for a file handle.

Comment: This is entirely backwards. A memory mapped file maps a file to memory so the code can act like it's reading/writing memory, and have those actually affect the contents of a file. What you want is the opposite: a handle that lets code act like it's reading/writing a file, but have that actually only affect memory instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities.

One would be to use `CreateFile`, but pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`. This *will* create a file, but tells Windows to attempt to keep as much of the file in the cache as possible. While this doesn't completely avoid creating a file, if you have enough memory it can often eliminate any (or much, anyway) I/O to/from the disk from happening.

Another possibility (though one I've never tested) would be to pass a handle to a named (or maybe even an anonymous) pipe. You can generally write to a pipe like you would a file, so as long as the crash dump writer just needs to be able to pass the handle to `WriteFile`, chances are pretty good this will work fine. From there, you could (for example) have another small program that would read the data from the pipe and write it to a socket. Obviously it would be nice to be able to avoid the extra processing to translate from pipe to socket, but such is life some times.

If you haven't tried it, you might want to test with just passing a socket handle to the crash dump writer. Although it's somewhat limited, Windows does support treating a socket handle like a normal file (or whatever) handle. There's certainly nothing close to a guarantee that it'll work, but it may be worth a shot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The crash dump is indeed process's memory. So, it doesn't make sense. Why don't you simply send the file and delete after successful send?

By the way, you can compress the file and send it, because crashdumps are usually big files.

Comment: I want to send the data from within the program, therefore I dont want to write the data out to a file because its simply wasted time (ill have to read it back in anyways) + additional hassle of having to worry about where to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to pass a file handle, so if you do anything else you're breaking the contract and (if it works at all) the behaviour will not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a **named pipe** handle. Pipe the data back to yourself.